# groovy multiple assignment with each closure fails

Tags: groovy

Why does this groovy code

```
def versionString = '10.15.20'
int major
int minor
int patch
(major, minor, patch) = versionString.split(/\./).each { Integer.parseInt(it) }
println "$major.$minor.$patch"
```

throw this exception

```
Caught: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object '10' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'int'
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object '10' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'int'
```

instead of displaying 10.15.20?

I.e. why are the variables assigned with the output from split() rather than the output of the closure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `collect`

```
(major, minor, patch) = versionString.split(/\./).collect { Integer.parseInt(it) }
```

Comment: `spread` also works: `(major, minor, patch) = versionString.split(/\./)*.toInteger()`